# Smoothing continuous functions in metric space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry

Let $(X,\rho)$ be a metric space. 
For any $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$, define the local Lipschitz constant of $f$ at $x$ by
$$ \Lambda_f(x) := \sup_{x'\in X\setminus\{x\}} \frac{|f(x)-f(x')|}{\rho(x,x,')}
.
$$

I conjecture that for every continuous $f:X\to[0,1]$ and $\eta>0$ there is an
$h:X\to[-1,1]$ such that $\overline f:=f+\eta h$ satisfies
$$
\Lambda_{\overline{f}}(x) \le \Lambda_f(x)
$$
for all $x\in X$
and
$$
|\Lambda_{\overline f}(x)-\Lambda_{\overline f}(x')| 
\le
 \eta^{-1}\rho(x,x')\max\{\Lambda_f(x),\Lambda_f(x')\}^2
$$
whenever $x,x'\in X$ and at least one of 
$\Lambda_{\overline f}(x),\Lambda_{\overline f}(x')<\infty$.

Question: Are results of this kind known? Conversely, is there an inherent reason why the above (or some close variant) cannot possibly hold? A brief search seems to indicate that results in this general spirit are obtained here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.11087.pdf ; am I at least correct about the "general spirit" part?

Comment: The "continuous" assumption can probably be dropped.